# Angular slider is not shown up

Tags: angular, angular-material

when i click the routerLink angular slider couldn't see the car text popup i added the code below of the html and
css file below.what i tried i attached the code and screenshot image
[image]

**content.component.html**

```
  <mat-drawer-container>
       <mat-drawer [opened]="opened" mode="side">
        <mat-list>
        <mat-list-item [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
            <mat-icon color="primary" mat-list-icon> directions_car </mat-icon>
                <a>Cars</a>
        </mat-list-item> 
    
        </mat-list>
    
       </mat-drawer>
      
    
    
    <mat-drawer-content>
    
        <div class="content">
            <router-outlet>
    
            </router-outlet>
        </div>
    
    </mat-drawer-content>
    
    </mat-drawer-container>
```

**content.component.scss**

```
.active{
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.mat-drawer{
    width: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    padding: 16px;
}

.mat-drawer-container{
    position: fixed;
    height: 89%;
    min-height: 89%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
}
a{
    color: darkblue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.active a{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**content.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuService } from '../menu.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.scss']
})
export class ContentComponent {
  opened = true;

  constructor(private menuService: MenuService)
  {
    this.menuService.isOpened.subscribe(data=>{
      this.opened = data;
    })
  }
}
```

i attached the ts file above what i tried so.thanks

Comment: Share a Stackblitz link to demo your problem.

Comment: i added the screen shot image above when i click the three dots need to show a slider

Comment: Screenshot isn't helpful. Share something we can fiddle with. You've only shared the HTML and CSS, whereas majority of Angular Material magic happens in TS files.

Comment: i updated the ts file above

Comment: Now the component depends on a service provider and we don't know what it contains. Furthermore, the component isn't standalone, so it's definitely part of a module. Did you import `MatSidenavModule` in there?

Comment: thanks it working now.i ran into the problem with ts